# Store redundant data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, database-schema

In RDMS I learned to normalize the database to minimize data redundancy and maximize consistency.

How does this work in cassandra since there seems to be no foreign keys concept.

Is this a bad design?

```
MeasurementId | SensorId | SensorLocation | SensorName | Value | Timestamp
```

Should this rather be:

```
MeasurementId | FK_SensorId | Value | Timestamp
```

and

```
SensorId | SensorLocation | SensorName
```

Or is cassandra good in compaction / compression out of the box and I should not care to store same values over and over again (as long as I am sure that the data will not change (e.g. SensorName will never change for a sensor))

Answer (score 0):

Basic technique for data modelling in cassandra is model your data based on the queries you need.

You should not be afraid of de-normalizing your data since joins are not possible in cassandra.

compression and compaction can be set by you on each table based on your requirements.